# Excluding posts by meta, and also keeping posts without the meta

Tags: filters, query, post-meta, meta-query

**edit:** Think I managed to figure it out, check the answer right under here, or click the following link:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51175/15809

---

I've been trying to find a way to exclude posts with 2 meta keys + values, but also keep the posts without the metas at all.

I looked into parse query request and have this in my `functions.php`:

```
function filter_out_efter15_posts( $request ) {
    $dummy_query = new WP_Query();
    $dummy_query->parse_query( $request );

    if ( $dummy_query->is_home() || $dummy_query->is_category('notiser') ) {
        $request['meta_query'][0]['key'] = 'efter15';
        $request['meta_query'][0]['value'] = 'Nej';
        $request['meta_query'][0]['compare'] = '=';
        $request['meta_query'][0]['type'] = 'CHAR';

        $request['meta_query'][1]['key'] = 'show_on_front_page';
        $request['meta_query'][1]['value'] = 'Ja';
        $request['meta_query'][1]['compare'] = '=';
        $request['meta_query'][1]['type'] = 'CHAR';

        return $request;
    }
    else {
        return $request;
    }
```

As you can see above, queries on the front page/home and on the category **notiser** (only category with posts that have these metas) filters out any posts with the meta key `efter15` with the value `Nej`, and meta key `show_on_front_page` with the value `Ja`.

However, when I go to a tag page, the above function will not alter anything, and thus *all* posts with that tag will show up. I still want the posts with the metas filtered out.

I could add `$dummy_query->is_tag()`, but then it would filter out all the other posts that does not have the metas. Obviously I cannot set specific tags, like with the category.

Hopefully you'll understand what I'm trying to do. Is there a clean and good way to deal with this? I'd like to keep the number of queries to a minimum, and there are 20k+ posts in the database so I don't know about running all of them into `post__not_in`, read it might slow things down a bit.

Do I have to use a custom select query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think I managed to solve this.

What I did was to add the following in my `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'exclude_my_posts' );    

function exclude_my_posts( $where ) {
    global $wpdb;

    //  For the front page. Hide posts with "efter15" set to "Ja", and only show posts with "show_on_front_page" set to "Nej"
    if (is_front_page()) {
        return $where . " AND $wpdb->posts.ID NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'efter15' AND meta_value = 'Ja' ) AND $wpdb->posts.ID NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'show_on_front_page' AND meta_value = 'Nej' )";
    }
    //  Always show all in dashboard
    elseif (is_admin()) {
        return $where;
    }
    //  Everywhere else: Hide posts with "efter15" set to "Ja"
    else {
        return $where . " AND $wpdb->posts.ID NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'efter15' AND meta_value = 'Ja' )";
    }

}
```

And in my index.php file - which is also used for category, tag etc (therefore the is_front_page()) for now at least:

```
<?php if (is_front_page()) {
    query_posts(array('category_name' => 'notiser', 'paged' => get_query_var('paged')));
} ?>
```

Then follows the loop and the rest. Looks good so far.